# C - write() input data to file

Tags: c

The user inputs, for 2 students, the name, ID, date of birth, gender and marital status. I should then write each input individually to a file. This is my code.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int fd, i;
    char name[20], id[10], dob[10], gender[7], status[10];
    fd = open("lab45.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, S_IRWXU);
    for (i = 1; i < 3; i = i + 1)
    {
        printf("\n\nStudent %d", i);
        printf("\n-Name: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", name);
        printf("\n-ID: ");
        scanf("%s", id);
        printf("\n-Date of birth: ");
        scanf("%s", dob);
        printf("\n-Gender: ");
        scanf("%s", gender);
        printf("\n-Marital status: ");
        scanf("%s", status);
        write(fd, &name, 20);
        write(fd, &id, 10);
        write(fd, &dob, 10);
        write(fd, &gender, 7);
        write(fd, &status, 10);
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

I input the following:

> Student 1
>
> -Name: John Smith
>
> -ID: JS3019
>
> -Date of birth: 14/10/90
>
> -Gender: male
>
> -Marital status: single
>
> Student 2
>
> -Name: Jane Doe
>
> -ID: JD0192
>
> -Date of birth: 13/12/99
>
> -Gender: female
>
> -Marital status: married

This is what I see in the text file afterwards.

> John Smith\00\00\00\00\00\00\A0@\00JS3019\00\00\C0\F414/10/90\00\00male\00\00\00single\00\00\EDJane
> Doe\00h\00\00\00\00\00\00\A0@\00JD0192\00\00\C0\F413/12/99\00\00female\00married\00\ED

Is this normal or there is something wrong in my code?

Comment: You are writing fixed-width strings into the file, so you are getting them padded with some garbage if the actual data is shorter.

Comment: The "weird" characters are the garbage, then. Is there a better way to write the strings to the file?

Comment: @phantom `fprintf` is like `printf` but writes to a file.

Comment: See @Carl Norum answer. `fprintf` or `fputs` are the alternatives

Comment: fprintf is easy but I am to use write() only.

Comment: use the strlen() function to determine the length of each string.  Or to keep each field so it can be parsed, later, by separating each field by a delimiter, such as a ','

Comment: regarding the calls to scanf():  1) limit the length of each string input so no buffer overflow occurs.  2) always check the returned value from the call to assure the operation was successful.  3) using [\n] is a very bad idea for scanf format strings.  Much better to have a simple while loop that reads until '\n' is consumed (due to a %s format specifier will stop on any white space (' ', \t, \n, EOF, etc)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you see is the result of writing the entire arrays to the file rather than just the parts containing data. You can either:

1. Use `fprintf` to print string data to the file rather than using `write`:

   ```
   FILE *f = fdopen(fd, "w");
   fprintf(f, "%s", name);
   ```
2. Change the length value you pass to `write` to include only the used data:

   ```
   write(fd, &name, strlen(name));
   ```

Comment: I used strlen() in write. The data is saved correctly for the first student but for the second student there is the garbage characters:

John SmithJS123414/02/90malesingleJane DoeJD541214/03/99femalemarried\00\00\00\00\A0@\00JD0192\00\00\C0\F413/12/99\00\00female\00married\00\ED

Comment: Those both look good; it just looks like you didn't truncate the file before writing.

Comment: Also, I need to read the data from the file and display it on screen afterwards. This is why I used fixed-length strings. Using strlen here will make it impossible to display the different data on the screen.

Comment: I was not sure if it was normal that there were the garbage characters. I thought maybe there should have been spaces instead.

Comment: @Phantom `write` is designed for writing raw binary data. If you want to write strings, you should use `fprintf`

Comment: There no way to properly write() fixed-length strings to a file and then read from the file to output the contents to the screen? The teacher says to use write() only.

Comment: write a delimiter between each field, then the file can be read in, field by field, using the delimiter.  I suggest using ',' for the delimiter.